# Session in Laravel is only available in local class

Tags: laravel

I'm currently building an API with laravel. Having faced the authentification, I implemented it. In my authentification controller I set a Session: `Session::put('value1','value2');`. When trying to access this session from my middleware class `Session::get('value1')` it gives me null as a return. How can I make a "session_start()" in laravel?

Comment: Api's are usually supposed to be stateless. You shouldn't use sessions.

Comment: The API routes, by default, don't have sessions enabled at all.

Comment: See https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/bb969c61d41ec479adbe4a6da797831002b75092/app/Http/Kernel.php - look for the `Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession` middleware.

Answer (score 1):

PHP (and Laravel has a consequence) associate the session to a browser through a specific Cookie, which is set in the browser. In Laravel, the cookie is called `laravel_session` while PHP usually names it `PHPSESSID`. This works because the browser will automatically send the cookie with every request made to the server, allowing your laravel application to match session cookie <-> session data and enabling you to successfully call `Session::get('value1')`

Now, you are not using a browser. You are making API requests, so there is nothing automatically managing a session cookie.

There are some hacks you could do to make it work (i.e. manually managing the cookies in your API requests) but you really shouldn't do it: it is an antipattern and it will create a lot of problems.

Comment: Session identifiers being stored in a cookie is actually a general feature of most web frameworks like e.g. Spring (Java), express.js (JavaScript on Node.js) and .NET to name a few.

Comment: Yeah sure, I only named PHP and laravel because of the context but it's a standard practice in web development